# Is it possible to apply countdown on my facebook page using my own JQuery code and images?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like post a image in the background and running timer on my facebook business page.

Is it possible to do by my own code?. Because i visit there are some website links, they are providing those kind of things example below link

https://www.powr.io/plugins/countdown-timer/standalone?id=17270232&platform=facebook

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of is by using a Page App/Tab that´s connected to your Page. That way, you can use any code you want in the Page App iframe. Anywhere else, there can be no custom JavaScript.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs/

One other way would be Facebook Live Video, all the information you need can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/

Comment: is it any other way to add the image and do countdown on facebook post?

Comment: i have added one more possibility, live video. it´s a lot of work just for a countdown though. and no, there is no other way.